# Easier way to calculate numeric multiplier suffix

Tags: javascript, jquery, numbers, exponent

```
function num(n) {
  if (n >= 1000 && n < 10000) return (n/1000).toFixed(3) + "K";
  if (n >= 10000 && n < 100000) return (n/1000).toFixed(1) + "K";
  if (n >= 100000 && n < 1000000) return (n/1000).toFixed(0) + "K";
  if (n >= 1000000 && n < 10000000) return (n/1000000).toFixed(3) + "M";
  if (n >= 10000000 && n < 100000000) return (n/1000000).toFixed(1) + "M";
  if (n >= 100000000 && n < 1000000000) return (n/1000000).toFixed(0) + "M";
  if (n >= 1000000000 && n < 10000000000) return (n/1000000000).toFixed(3) + "B";
  if (n >= 10000000000 && n < 100000000000) return (n/1000000000).toFixed(1) + "B";
  if (n >= 100000000000 && n < 1000000000000) return (n/1000000000).toFixed(0) + "B";
  if (n >= 1000000000000 && n < 10000000000000) return (n/1000000000000).toFixed(3) + "T";
  if (n >= 10000000000000 && n < 100000000000000) return (n/1000000000000).toFixed(1) + "T";
  if (n >= 100000000000000 && n < 1000000000000000) return (n/1000000000000).toFixed(0) + "T";
  return n;
}
```

Since at some point I'm probably going to be going upwards to the power of hundreds, is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: http://numeraljs.com/ `numeral(10000000000000000).format('0a'); )`

Comment: One simple optimization: use `else if` so you stop at the first matching one. And then you don't need to test `>=`, just `<`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function formatNumber(number) {
    var i = 0; units = [ "", "K", "M", "B", "T" ]; // etc
    while (number > 1000) {
        number /= 1000;
        i += 1;
    }
    return Math.floor(number * 1000) / 1000 + units[i];
}

formatNumber(1234567); // 1.234M
formatNumber(1230567); // 1.23M
```

---

This might be faster for very large numbers:

```
function formatNumber(number) {
    var i; units = [ "", "K", "M", "B", "T" ]; // etc
    i = Math.round(Math.log(number) / Math.log(10) / 3);
    number /= Math.pow(10, i * 3);
    return Math.floor(number * 1000) / 1000 + units[i];
}

formatNumber(1234567); // 1.234M
formatNumber(1230567); // 1.23M
```

Comment: Would this preform well for very large numbers such as 10^100 when it's being called 100 times a second?

Comment: @DarkestSoul I added a solution that uses `log` to avoid having to do many iterations. I don't know which is faster. Test it. It's very possible either solution can be optimized.

Comment: @Halcyon I like your answer, upvoted. Run some test and found difference in what OP is expecting and `formatNumber` is returning: `Num: 123456 OP: 123K Ans: 123.456K,

Num: 1234567 OP: 1.235M Ans: 1.234M,

Num: 1230567 OP: 1.231M Ans: 1.23M,

Num: 12345678 OP: 12.3M Ans: 12.345M,

Num: 123456789 OP: 123M Ans: 123.456M,

Num: 1234567890 OP: 1.235B Ans: 1.234B,

Num: 12345678901 OP: 12.3B Ans: 12.345B,

Num: 123456789012 OP: 123B Ans: 123.456B`. Here's fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/9vs2q4ed/ if you want to play with it.

Comment: @Tushar see Leo's answer.

Comment: `formatNumber(31622); // 31.622K`
`formatNumber(31623); // 0.031M`

Comment: I changed the `.round()` function to `.floor()` since it was rounding up the exponent value given to `i`, and thus selecting the wrong unit format when `i = x.5`. Also fixes `number` receiving the wrong `.pow()` value.

Answer (score 0):

My approach here:

```
function num(n) {
  if(n < 1000) {
    return n
  }

  var units = ['K', 'M', 'B', 'T']
  for(var i = -1; n >= 1000; i++) {
    n /= 1000
  }

  if(n >= 100) {
    return n.toFixed(0) + units[i]
  }
  if(n >= 10) {
    return n.toFixed(1) + units[i]
  }
  return n.toFixed(3) + units[i]
}
```

Comment: Ran some tests http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/9vs2q4ed/1/, found difference between what OP's code is returning and this code returns `Num: 1234 OP: 1.234K Ans: 1.234K

Num: 12345 OP: 12.3K Ans: 12.345K

Num: 123456 OP: 123K Ans: 123.456K

Num: 1234567 OP: 1.235M Ans: 1.235M

Num: 1230567 OP: 1.231M Ans: 1.231M

Num: 12345678 OP: 12.3M Ans: 12.346M

Num: 123456789 OP: 123M Ans: 123.457M

Num: 1234567890 OP: 1.235B Ans: 1.235B

Num: 12345678901 OP: 12.3B Ans: 12.346B

Num: 123456789012 OP: 123B Ans: 123.457B`

Comment: @Tushar Apparently your test case is wrong. In your code `y = bytes.toFixed(3) + units[i]` always executes. In my code it executes only if `n < 10` after the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the finished function with help from Halcyon.

```
function fnum(number) {
    var i, x, units = [ "", "K", "M", "B", "T", "Qa", "Qi", "Sx", "Sp", "Oc", "No", "Dc" ]; 
    i = Math.floor(Math.log(number) / Math.log(10) / 3);
    x = Math.floor(Math.log(number) / Math.log(10)) % 3;
    number /= Math.pow(10, i * 3);
    return ((number * 1000) / 1000).toFixed(77 % ((x * 2) + 3)) + units[i];
}
```

Will return a number from 0 to 999 to 2 decimal places when formatted to 1s and 10s, and 0 decimal places when formatted to 100s, and then add a numerical suffix. Add additional suffixes as required.

`fnum(22000); >> 22.00K`
`fnum(153000000); >> 153M`
`fnum(2,230,000,000,000); >> 2.23T`

Answer (score 0):

```js
function fnum(number) {
    var i, x, units = [ "", "K", "M", "B", "T", "Qa", "Qi", "Sx", "Sp", "Oc", "No", "Dc" ]; 
    i = Math.floor(Math.log(number) / Math.log(10) / 3);
    x = Math.floor(Math.log(number) / Math.log(10)) % 3;
    number /= Math.pow(10, i * 3);
    return ((number * 1000) / 1000).toFixed(77 % ((x * 2) + 3)) + units[i];
}
console.log(fnum(22000))
console.log(fnum(153000000))
console.log(fnum(2200000000000))
```

Comment: Explaining your code will be helpful for other users.